# How to keep document creation idempotent in azure-cosmosdb (Document DB)?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I would like to achieve idempotency of creating documents with azure cosmos DB. Please let me know if cosmos-db(document db) supports this out of the box.

I am using SQL api for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, by using the Upsert functionality.

One possibility is to create documents like this:

```
var client = new CosmosClient(endpointUrl, primaryKey, clientOptions);
var container = client.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);

var transactionalBatch = container.CreateTransactionalBatch(new PartitionKey(document.pk));
transactionalBatch.UpsertItem(document);

await transactionalBatch.ExecuteAsync();
```

By using the *UpsertItem* instead of *CreateItem* functionality you can execute the same batch multiple times without causing changes unless you change the document.

This example is meant for the Cosmos Db V3, more samples can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3